# Does getElementById() and getElementByName() are same for IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, getelementbyid

Today I found a strange behavior with IE9.(I am working on an old application which works fine on IE9 to make it compatible with firefox and chrome) I have written this snippet of code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(){
            var o1 = document.getElementById("t0_ship_bill");
            console.log(o1.checked);
            console.log("Its executed.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="test()">Test</button>
    <input type="Checkbox" class="checkbox" name="t0_ship_bill" > 
</body>
</html>
```

You can see inside test() function I have used `getElementById("t0_ship_bill")` where as in html there is no such element is defined with that id.Still IE9 does not throws error ,it is able to get the element by the name.

Output:

Firefox:
`TypeError: o1 is null`

IE9:
`LOG: true`

`LOG: Its executed.`

Any one having any idea how IE9 able to get the element without ID on it where as firefox and chrome throws error ?

This is the main reason because of which my application throws error on firefox on many lines where as works fine on IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 'feature' of IE. Their implementation of `getElementById` initially searches for elements with the given `id` attribute. If none are found, it then searches for elements by the `name` attribute, which is against the spec.

In your example the behaviour of Firefox is correct, as your `input` has no `id` property.

If you want to find elements by their name, use the `getElementsByName()` method instead.

Comment: Note that the behavior can vary with both functions, based on the document mode.  For best results, use the HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`).  For more, see getElementById (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx) and getElementsByName (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536438(v=vs.85).aspx).